# React application can't access NodeJs backend on Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, express

So i have a React application , and a NodeJS (Express) Application running on port 4000.

i created the build for the react app and deployed it along with the backend on Apache.

The react app works fine , but the Frontend calls for the Node API dont seem to work , here's my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80 > 
    ServerName  example.com  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   <Directory /var/www/html > 
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
          Require all granted 
   </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

The front end doesnt seem to reach the backend am i missing something in the config ?

By the way in the front end i use Axios as a http client to make requests to the backend with its URL http://localhost:4000/ , and the app works fine in my local machine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, provide us the error message you get or some useful logs to help us help you.

Comment: Here's a capture of the network tab on my React app : https://imgur.com/a/zjxC7ut , the GET request doesnt go through , even though the API endpoint works fine.

Comment: OK, in the question you say "and the app works fine in my local machine", so I have to suppose that what is not working is the deploy on a remote machine, right? You should put the remote back-end URL instead of `localhost` in your production build.

Comment: so is it going to work ? because when i try to access example.com:4000 from my machine it doesnt succeed , normally it should give a response for the GET / endpoint

Comment: The answer you proposed should work if the Front end was in local and the backend was deployed , right ? or am i mistaken.